# pd.saveto and pd.read_csv adds header and index column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have a dataframe which i save like this:

```
Y_train_1.head()

0    4691.0
1    4661.0
2    4631.0
3    4601.0
4    4571.0

Y_train_1.to_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',')
```

then i read this again like this:

```
Y_train = pd.read_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',', index_col=None, header=None))
Y_train.head()
```

[image]

using

```
Y_train = pd.read_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',', index_col=[0], header=None)
```

i still get a dataframe like this, which is not the same as before?

[image]

How can i get the same Dataframe as before?

usi

Thanks,R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If working with `Series` add parameter `squeeze=True`:

```
print (type(Y_train_1))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (Y_train_1)
0    4691.0
1    4661.0
2    4631.0
3    4601.0
4    4571.0
dtype: float64

Y_train_1.to_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',', header=None)
Y_train = pd.read_csv("Y_train.csv", 
                      sep='\t', 
                      decimal=',', 
                      index_col=[0], 
                      squeeze=True, 
                      header=None)
print (Y_train)
0
0    4691.0
1    4661.0
2    4631.0
3    4601.0
4    4571.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

---

```
Y_train_1.to_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',', index=False, header=None)
Y_train = pd.read_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',', squeeze=True, header=None)
print (Y_train)
0    4691.0
1    4661.0
2    4631.0
3    4601.0
4    4571.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: i tried `Y_train = pd.read_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',', index_col=[0], header=None)` and updated my problem with the dataframe i get using this @jezrael

Comment: @raffa_sa - check last 2 paraghaphs

Comment: it worked with this `Y_train = pd.read_csv("Y_train.csv", sep='\t', decimal=',', index_col=[0], squeeze=True, header = None)` - i had to add header=None otherwise i loose one row - thanks!

Comment: @raffa_sa - tested solutions and need also `header=None`

Comment: we found out the same thing ;) @jezrael